# How to disable Ceph Dashboard Anonymous Access?

Tags: grafana, ceph

I have installed a Ceph cluster V15 (Octopus). Following the general setup guide a Grafana Dashboard is installed during bootstrapping the cluster. This is a nice feature.
But the dashboard can be access on port :3000 from anonymous without authentication.

I guess this is because of the configuration of the  anonymous mode in /etc/grafana/grafana.ini:

```
[auth.anonymous]
enabled = true
```

How can I disable this mode?

There are several 'ceph dashboard' commands available but I can't figure out how to tweek the default grafana.ini file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an instance of the grafana.ini file on the grafana host:

```
/var/lib/ceph/<UUID>/grafana.host1/etc/grafana/grafana.ini
```

You can edit that file and set the option `auth.anonymous.enabled` to 'false'

```
...
[auth.anonymous]
  enabled = false
  org_name = 'My Org.'
  org_role = 'Viewer'
...
```

restart the container with

```
# ceph orch restart grafana
```

now your changes should be applied. You can login now with the default user/password 'admin' / 'admin'